# How to color all Walls in Black

Tags: python, colors, revit, pyrevit

I want to color in Revit with Pyrevit some Elements:
all Walls in Black,
the windows in green and 
Doors in Pink.

I found this solution but it´s not working:

```
Example

"""
All elements of Category
Get all elements of the specified category from Model.
"""

#Imports.
import csv
from Autodesk.Revit.DB import FilteredElementCollector, BuiltInCategory, BuiltInParameter
from Autodesk.Revit import revit,DB
from pyrevit.coreutils import colors

# We will need to access the active document. The UIApplication instance is referenced by the `__revit__` builtin variable, provided by pyRevit execution engine
doc = __revit__.ActiveUIDocument.Document
uidoc = __revit__.ActiveUIDocument

classpyrevit.coreutils.colors.RGB(name='default', red=0, green=0, blue=0):
    ALICEBLUE = RGB('aliceblue', 240, 248, 255)
    PINK = RGB(name='pink', red=255, green=192, blue=203)
    DARKVIOLET = RGB(name='darkviolet', red=148, green=0, blue=211

walls = FilteredElementCollector(doc).OfCategory(BuiltInCategory.OST_Walls).WhereElementIsNotElementType()

for wall in walls
    colors.COLORS['pink']

door_collector = FilteredElementCollector(doc).OfCategory(BuiltInCategory.OST_Doors).WhereElementIsNotElementType()
for door in door_collector
    colors.COLORS['aliceblue']

window_collector = FilteredElementCollector(doc).OfCategory(BuiltInCategory.OST_Windows).WhereElementIsNotElementType()
for window in window_collector
    colors.COLORS['darkviolet']
```

May you can help me!!
Thanks a lot. 
Regards

Comment: I don't know `revit`, but in your `for` loops you did not change the loop variable, e.g. `wall` or `door`. It seems it should be `door.color = colors.COLORS['aliceblue']` or something like this.

Answer (score 0):

You are in luck!

The Building Coder just discussed an easy way to [change the element colour in a view](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2020/06/changing-element-colour-and-material.html).

That should exactly fit your bill.